# Sending mail using php mail() -- abusing 'from' email address

Tags: php, forms, security, email

I'm implementing a contact form in php using the mail() function. In the contact form, I ask for the user's email address, and upon submission I send their message to my own email address.

Here is my php code:

```
    $to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $from_name = $_POST['InputName'];
    $from_email = $_POST['InputEmail'];
    $subject = 'Message from '.$from_name;
    $message = $_POST['InputMessage'];
    $headers = 'From: '.$from_email."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$from_email.
        "\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();
    $mailsuccess = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

After testing this, I realize a person can send me an email masquerading as someone else's valid email address. For example, during testing, I used my friend's email and sent myself a message. Isn't this a security problem? In my gmail account, I did get a warning that this email may not be from that person, but if it's not clearly spam I usually ignore that warning.

For example, if Bob (bob@gmail.com) sends a message through the contact form masquerading as Chris (chris@gmail.com), I will respond in my email to Chris. Chris thinks his email is hacked because he never sent that email. Is this generally an issue? Or is there a way to make it safer?

Comment: That issue will happen on any contact form where sign in is not required, your code does have other issues though

Comment: This is a huge general issue throughout e-mails, some Webmail clients such as `Roundcube` let you have multiple identities, each with its own e-mail address, whether or not it actually belongs to you. There are ways to mitigate this using DKIM and other means but generally aren't perfect, and definitely won't be in your case; unless you add some sort of `Sign-in with Google` functionality and get their e-mail from the Google APIs, that way you'd have site-wide login and a trustworthy e-mail, obviously just Google would be silly, +standard account which requires verification of email ownership.

Comment: Another solution is to send them an email, asking them to confirm their address before the message is sent.

Comment: The way to make it safer would be to first send an e-mail to `chris@gmail.com` to ask him to click a link if in-fact it was him who filled in the contact form else to ignore the contact request.

Comment: @BaileyHerbert 13 seconds before me haha

Comment: Thanks, sending a confirmation email seems to be the most straightforward method. @LemuelBotha can you elaborate on the other issues with the code?

Comment: The user can easily input multiple email address in the from field causing the same email to be sent from multiple address, you need to add validation to the from field to ensure only one address can be submitted

Comment: @LemuelBotha Right now the form data is being validated just using <input type="email" ...> which prevents me from inputting multiple email addresses. Does this still require further validation on the php side?

Comment: @shimizu Yes, because there are still ways for users to bypass client-side validation, you need to handle validation both client and server side. Examples of methods users could bypass your validation is to use the Tamper Data tool or to copy the source code, modify the action and tag type and still submit

Comment: @LemuelBotha Worse than multiple from addresses, sanitized data is written directly to the header section. This allows the client to specify any headers they like.  The standard attack there would be for a malicious client to use your server to launch spam e-mail campaigns.

Comment: @Aurand you are 100% correct

Answer (score 1):

It's called email spoofing. SMTP is not a very secure protocol. It's always been possible to spoof. Unfortunately there is no way around it unless every email server on earth makes changes to fix that, which is unlikely.

It's how a lot of phishing and spam happens.